# IP ranges for login.microsoftonline.com and graph.microsoft.com endpoints

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, office365

I whìtelisted below URLs to connect Office 365 within my organization server, but still cannot connect to Microsoft Graph API. Later I found that `login.microsoftonline.com` is unable to establish a socket connection.

Therefore my network guys suggested to collect all IP ranges for below whitelist URLs. Any comment is this the right way to do this, and if yes, from where I can find the IP ranges for below URLs.

Whitelisted URLs:

- login.microsoftonline.com
- graph.microsoft.com

Python code:

```
import msal

app = msal.ConfidentialClientApplication(
    config['client_id'],
    authority = "www.login.microsoftonline.com/{tenantId}",
    client_credential = config['secret'],
    proxies = {"http":"http://user:password@proxy.com"}
)

socket.connect(host,port)
#host = login.microsoftonline.com
#port = 443
```

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft has published a large list of endpoints and IP ranges used for their global services, which you can find at [aka.ms/o365endpoints](https://aka.ms/o365endpoints). You'll be primarily interested in the [Microsoft 365 Common and Office Online](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/enterprise/urls-and-ip-address-ranges?redirectSourcePath=%252fen-us%252farticle%252fOffice-365-URLs-and-IP-address-ranges-8548a211-3fe7-47cb-abb1-355ea5aa88a2&view=o365-worldwide#microsoft-365-common-and-office-online) section.

Your `authority` value should also be `https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant_id}`

Comment: What's "authority" value? Where should it be set, I'm on Ubuntu and can't even get an ip from NSLOOKUP, not even using their azure-dns.com nameservers?